# Is the maximinm value of network.http.pipelining.maxrequests still 8?

Tags: fedora, centos, firefox

I've detected some slowness in Firefox 17 under Fedora 18, so I decided to modify some configuration options.

So, the question is: Does someone know if the maximum value of **network.http.pipelining.maxrequests** is still 8?

I find people saying that if I put more than 8, it will be ignored. It seems weird to me that the default value of Fedora and also Centos is 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.  The discussions for this from 2010 refer to an annotated  `#define` from [nsHttp.h](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/netwerk/protocol/http/src/nsHttp.h) in the Mozilla CVS tree:

```
// hard upper limit on the number of requests that can be pipelined
#define NS_HTTP_MAX_PIPELINED_REQUESTS 8
```

However, apparently, "For Gecko, XULRunner, and Firefox, *CVS trunk is no longer the trunk*, and is instead used for Gecko 1.9 / Firefox 3 and the 1.9.0.* / 3.0.* security releases."

The [corresponding file](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttp.h) in the current "mozilla-release" branch (which I presume includes 17, and it is the same as the "-esr17" branch) does not have that define, and that identifier does not appear in the release tree at all.  The actual variable that's [set here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpConnectionMgr.cpp#2128) using the enum name (MAX_PIPELINED_REQUESTS) from nsHttp.h is `mMaxPipelinedRequests`, and looking at the other references to that, its only restriction would seem to be that it's an unsigned 16-bit value, meaning it has a range of 0-65535.